# Raft protocol split brain

Tags: raft

studying raft, I can’t understand one thing, for example, I have a cluster of 6 nodes, and I have 3 partitions with a replication factor of 3, let’s say that a network error has occurred, and now 3 nodes do not see the remaining 3 nodes, until they remain available for clients, and for example, the record SET 5 came to the first formed cluster , and in this case it will pass? because replication factor =3 and majority will be 2? it turns out you can get split brain using raft protocol?

Answer (score 0):

In case of 6 nodes, the majority is 4. So if you have two partitions of three nodes, neither of those partitions will be able to elect a leader or commit new values.

When a raft cluster is created, it is configured with specific number of nodes. And the majority of those nodes is required to either elect a leader or commit a log message.

In case of a raft cluster, every node has a replica of data. I guess we could say that the replication factor is equal to cluster side in a raft cluster. But I don't think I've ever seen replication factor term being used in consensus use case.

Few notes on cluster size.

Traditionally, cluster size is 2*N+1, where N is number of nodes a cluster can lose and still be operational - as the rest of nodes still have majority to elect a leader or commit log entries. Based on that, a cluster of 3 nodes may lose 1 node; a cluster of 5 may lose 2.

There is no much point (from consensus point of view) to have cluster of size 4 or 6. In case of 4 nodes total, the cluster may survive only one node going offline - it can't survive two as the other two are not the majority and they won't be able to elect a leader or agree on progress. Same logic applies for 6 nodes - that cluster can survive only two nodes going off. Having a cluster of 4 nodes is more expensive as we can have support the same single node outage with just 3 nodes - so cluster of 4 is a just more expensive with no availability benefit.

There is a case when cluster designers do pick cluster of size 4 or 6. This is when the system allows stale reads and those reads can be executed by any node in a cluster. To support larger scale of potentially stale reads, a cluster owner adds more nodes to handle the load.